# How to plot the 1st element value of a 2D point against time?

Tags: code-request

```
P1[t_] := 
 Module[{pts}, 
  pts = Cases[Plot[uwave1[t, 0.5, z]^2, {z, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> All],
     Line[a_] :> a, Infinity];
  RegionCentroid@
   Polygon@
    Join[{{pts[[1, 1, 1]], 0}}, pts[[1]], {{pts[[1, -1, 1]], 0}}]]
```

Here P1[t] is a point $(a,b)$ in 2D space which varies with time. How shall I plot the value of $a$ against time?

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using `First`:

```
Plot[First[P1[t]], {t, 0, 8 Pi}]
```